# How to cover image with an icon

Tags: css, image, icons, pseudo-element

Here's example https://jsbin.com/rekaxa/edit?html,css,output.
I'd like to put that red circle(an icon) over the image, but to keep html straightforward. What's the best way(maybe totally different) to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said where you want the icon to be so I picked the dead center of the div.

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 280px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* adjust as requiured */
  left: 50%; /* adjust as required */
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff" />
</div>
```